# hallo or hello: etymology dilemma

Tags: etymology, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Does anybody know the etymology of the main greeting in English: hallo?

Besides that I wish to know the difference between the terms *hallo* and *hello*.

I have to know!

Comment: Is "hallo" a common greeting in English? Also, this sounds like an ELU question to me.

Comment: @KenB I agree, I think etymology questions like this would be a better fit on EL&U, and "hallo" is relatively uncommon, especially by comparison with "hello" and other greetings. Regardless, here is a place to start: [etymonline.com result for *hello* and *hallo*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hallo&searchmode=none)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology and orthography of a word, and therefore a better fit for EL&U (which is currently not an option for suggested migration?).

Answer (score 9):

The quickest source for English etymologies is [**etymonline.com**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hallo&searchmode=none), which will give you this:

> 1883, alteration of ***hallo***, itself an alteration of ***holla***, *hollo*, a shout to attract attention, which seems to go back to at least c.1400. Perhaps from *holla!* “stop, cease.” OED cites Old High German *hala, hola*, emphatic imperative of *halon*, *holon* “to fetch,” “used especially in hailing a ferryman.” Fowler lists *halloo, hallo, halloa, halloo, hello, hillo, hilloa, holla, holler, hollo, holloa, hollow, hullo*, and writes, “The multiplicity of forms is bewildering ....” Popularity as a greeting coincides with use of the telephone, where it won out over Alexander Graham Bell's suggestion, *ahoy*. Central telephone exchange operators were known as *hello-girls* (1889).

Etymonline's main source, and the “authoritative” English source, is the *Oxford English Dictionary*. This is in constant process of revision; the current state is available online by subscription, the first edition is available free from archive.org (I give the volume-by-volume links below). Here you will find all the variants above as distinct headwords, as well as a number of variants ending in {-oo}. It offers (*s.v.* **Holla**) as another possible source or influence French *holà*,“stop!, wait!” recorded since the 15th century. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hallo) *s.v.* **hallo** gives parallels in other European languages and suggests that it represents “Old English *hēlā, ǣlā, ēalā* (“O!, alas!, oh!, lo!”), equivalent to *hey* +‎ *lo*.” There's no evidence for the OE connection, but I think it very likely that *hey*, *ha*, *ho* lies at the bottom of all these.

The upshot appears to be that something like /'hVlo/, with a lengthened endstressed version /hə'loː/ or /hə'luː/, has been around since late Middle English (and may go farther back) as a cry to catch someone's attention. Its ultimate origin is obscure.

I think the orthographic variants should probably be regarded as just that: spelling preferences for a word with various trivially different pronunciations. Here is a Google Ngram which graphs the occurrence of the most frequent 19th and 20th century variants against the occurrence of *hello*; as you see, *hello* has been for three or four generations the most popular. The crossover came in US English about 1895 and in British English about 1920:
[image]

***OED 1* at archive.org:**

[A-B](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/n23/mode/2up) 
[C](http://archive.org/stream/oed02arch#page/n5/mode/2up) 
[D-E](http://archive.org/stream/oed03arch#page/n3/mode/2up) 
[F-G](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio04murruoft#page/n5/mode/2up) 
[H](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt105murruoft#page/n5/mode/2up) 
[I-K](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt205murruoft#page/n3/mode/2up) 
[L](http://archive.org/stream/oed6aarch#page/n5/mode/2up) 
[M-N](http://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/n3/mode/2up) 
[O-P](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/n5/mode/2up) 
[Q-R](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt108murruoft#page/n7/mode/2up) 
[S-Sh](http://archive.org/stream/oed8barch#page/n5/mode/2up) 
[Si-St](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt109murruoft#page/n7/mode/2up) 
[Su-Th](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt209murruoft#page/n7/mode/2up) 
[Ti-U](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/n5/mode/2up) 
[V-Z](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio102murruoft#page/n7/mode/2up)

Comment: The OED1 archive is great, would you like to add it here? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/source-for-etymological-study

Comment: @Hugo Fersher. As you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Being a Brit, I've always pronounced hello as hallo, and spelt hello as hallo and never known "hello" could be a correct spelling! When I left the UK in 1994 I became convined non-native and US speakers were mispronouncing and mispelling hello!

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking on **edit**. One thing you should note is this community is not a discussion forum and it encourages definitive answers with proper research and reference.

Comment: @si_l, I just don't get that.  I grew up in Yorkshire, live in the north-west and spend a lot of time in London, but I recognise 'hello' as being the main form, with 'hallo' as a bit of an oddity.  BTW in the comic-books I read as a boy, it was often 'hullo', but I think that was an attempt to represent 'hello/hallo' stressed on the O, with a schwa in the first syllable.